# yii2 ajax request redirect not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I tried to redirect the user after he click on a button.
But the redirection is not working.
This is my js code for handling the button click.

```
$('#MyButton').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo Url::to(['configurator/compare']) ?>',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    Ref : Ref,
    searchname: $("#searchname").val() , 
    searchby:$("#searchby").val() , 
    _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
  },
  success: function (data) {
  }
});
```

[The http request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1uUQ.png)

The request is executed but i'm not redirected to the url.
I stay on the same page when i click in the button.

Comment: You aren't actually redirecting anywhere though. It's just making an ajax POST request to a given URL.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted does not perform a redirect.

All it does is make an ajax POST request to the `url:` ('configurator/compare') and passes the parameters in `data:`

To perform a redirect you could do it in the `success:` callback, e.g.

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

You can either hardcode the URL in above, or base it on the output of the script you posted to, which is available by accessing `data` inside the `success` callback.

Comment: But will i be able to access the post data in my  controller through the redirection ?

Comment: I don't think you understand the flow of an ajax request. Your script makes a POST to `'configurator/compare'`. At that point, you can access the data you have posted via ajax (e.g. `searchname:`, `searchby:`). You can return anything from that script which will then be readable in the `success:` callback. At that point you can do redirection, or anything else. But you can't do a PHP redirect because the request is being made with ajax, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If  you don't want return any data to you 'success' function, than in your controller 'configurator', in method 'compare', after handling your data you can make redirection to 'view' which you want:

```
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    // do what you want with data
    return $this->redirect(['controller/action']);
```

Comment: but your ajax request will hit the error function because it cannot process the data it is receiving which is not a json response

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Below way.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
     $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{id:id},
            url : '<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("/property/favourite"); ?>',
            success: function(response){
                        window.location.href = '<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("/site/chat"); ?>';        
                    }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path in the controller and send the url back to the page.

```
public function actionAjaxMethod() {
    //my logic
    //if everything is successfulget the url path you want to redirect to.
    $url = Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("/controllerName/methodName");
   return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
      'status' => true,
      'url' => $url,
   ]);
}
```

In your view page all you do is

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.status) {
         //redirect the page to url.
         window.location.href = data.url;
    } 
},
```